# List of Tables names used in MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC, my company wanted me to work on an already built MVC application. There are lot of Tables and Stored procedures used in that application. Is there any way i can collect all the table names and the Stored Procedures names. The server and DB are been used by several applications in the company . So it makes more complicated in SQL server side to list them.

Thanks

Comment: **See the following Stack Overflow questions:**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219434/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418527

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420741

Comment: The links posted above are really helpful when i am working individually on sql server. But my question is how to find in mvc application. I have 100 of tables in my DB that are been used in other applications.

Comment: The original question seems to have been incorrectly marked as a duplicate question. The SO question links referenced relate to finding data objects (like tables) in SQL Server databases. The key acronym in the original question is MVC (Model, View, Controller), which is a newer variant of ASP.NET applications. ASP.NET applications using MVC may use SQL Server databases. The referenced links should have a ASP.NET MVC focus; but they do not. Either appropriate existing questions should be linked or the "marked as duplicate" designation should be dropped from this question.