# Why does my stored procedure not show up in my SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I created a database in SQL Server. I follow these:

```
Programmability -> Stored Procedures -> right click -> new stored procedures.
```

I write this code in my stored procedure:

```
create procedure Insert_Users_legal
(
    @name   nvarchar(50),
    @agentPosition  int,
    @email  varchar(50),
    @mobile char(11),
    @phone  char(11),
    @postalCode char(10),
    @address    nchar(10)
)
as
    set nocount on

    insert into users_legal (name, agentPosition, email, mobile, phone, postalCode, address)
    values (@name, @agentPosition, @email, @mobile, @phone, @postalCode, @address)

    select CAST(scope_identity() as int) as id_legalUser
    return
```

But when I save my stored procedure, it doesn't show up in stored procedure folder in the Object Explorer.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: In which DB Procedure is created. Try to use fully qualified name. You might be checking in wrong Database

Comment: @Mihai: I refreshed it frequently.

Comment: There is no "stored procedure folder" in a database; this is the functionality of the client you're using to access the database. You haven't said what client you're using... Having said that are you sure you've actually created the procedure? Does the procedure show up in [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/219510/458741)?

Comment: @NoDisplayName: no, I check in correct database. :(

Comment: execute this query `Select name FROM sys.procedures WHERE name LIKE '%Insert_Users_legal%'`

Comment: what happens when you run this `create procedure municipalityDB.dbo.Insert_Users_legal....` if you are not getting error then Procedure is created in some other DB

Comment: you cannot save in SSMS but you can compile.

Comment: Have you tried to execute `sp_helptext 'Insert_Users_legal'`?

Comment: You need to execute the statements that you wrote while writing the stored procedure. This was the mistake I was doing.

Comment: The simplest way... in object explorer, click on the "Stored Procedures" node and then press F5 on the keyboard.  This will refresh the list displayed within SQL Server Management Studio so that it matches what is in the actual database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

execute the following statements and it must create a stored procedure in your correct database:

```
/*****   use the correct database *****/
USE municipalityDB;
GO

/*****   Drop Procedure if already exist *****/
IF (OBJECT_ID('Insert_Users_legal') IS NOT NULL)
  DROP PROCEDURE Insert_Users_legal
GO

/*****   Now create the procedure *****/
create procedure Insert_Users_legal
(
@name           nvarchar(50),
@agentPosition  int,
@email          varchar(50),
@mobile         char(11),
@phone          char(11),
@postalCode     char(10),
@address        nchar(10),
@id_legalUser   INT OUTPUT   --<-- use output param to get new id 
)
as
BEGIN
 set nocount on;
  insert into users_legal (name,agentPosition,email,mobile,phone,postalCode,[address])
  values (@name,@agentPosition,@email,@mobile,@phone,@postalCode,@address)

  SELECT  @id_legalUser = scope_identity();     --<-- No need to cast as INT 
-- return    --<-- Not required   
END
GO


/*****   Check if procedure exists *****/
Select name FROM sys.procedures 
WHERE name LIKE '%Insert_Users_legal%'
GO
```

Comment: You do not need to write all of this code, if you would have selected the correct database from your SSMS from top left drop down list, it would have created the procedure in the correct database. anyway the important change I have made in this procedure's definition is the OUTPUT parameter for newly generated identity value. Using an output parameter will allow you to use this value in other places in your code, otherwise I don't see any point of just selecting it.

Answer (score 9):

First click on **Execute**, then click on **refresh**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, refreshing didn't help.
Disconnecting and reconnecting to the database resolved it for me.