# How to find stored procedures which are using 'My Database' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, rename

Is there any way I can find how many stored procedures are created referencing `My Database`?

IF I change database name from `My Database` to `No Database`, how to modify all the stored procedures referencing to my OLD database name to new database name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query to list all stored procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219434/query-to-list-all-stored-procedures)

Comment: Could help (manually) accomplish what you're after with a free search tool such as [Redgate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your stored procedures actually have the text 'My Database' in them, you can use this, replacing 'ADB' with 'DatabaseName':

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%ABD%'
```

Comment: Thank you. This query brings up all the stored procedures. How to modify these stored procedures with my New Database Name ??

Comment: You could do a REPLACE using other sys views.  I would recommend following Mike Guthrie's advice on using a search tool like Redgate SQL Search.  You are able to modify stored procs with it as well.