# Programmatically: List all stored procedures found in an entity framework model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to return all stored procedures names/types listed in the model browser

[image]

**Note**: it is not possible in the Model Browser to copy all listed items or even a single one.

Comment: Hm, you can use some SQL against the database to get a list of sprocs.  Would that work?  Or do you want an EF-specific solution?

Comment: @Amy Right. However, what I am looking for is a list of all procedures used in a single application.

Comment: There isn't really any way to get a list of the *used* sprocs, aside from getting a list of all the sprocs and then, one by one, checking to see if each is used.

Comment: Maybe use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219434/query-to-list-all-stored-procedures) as a starting point?  I'm trying to come up with a way of doing this in an EF-specific way.

Comment: @Amy, I am assuming that if they are listed in the browser or even wrapped in an entity framework object then there must be a way to get them.

Comment: Yes.  I just don't know how to do that in code.  Won't stop me from trying!  Will probably require reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the assembly's embedded resources for the SSDL. Functions with parameters and return types are described in Function elements.

[SSDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj652016)

If you have the source code, the SSDL is in the .edmx file.